# how to include Duplicated commands in history plugin?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use `history` a lot, but it seems that it will remove the Duplicated commands, how can I see all my commands include the Duplicated ones?

I use history plugin in zsh

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have `hist_ignore_all_dups` or `hist_ignore_dups` in your `.zshrc` file.

For me, I noticed that zsh keeps duplicated commands unless they are performed consecutively by default. For instead, cd, cd then ls will only keep cd and ls; however, cd, ls cd, will have all three in the history.

Look at the setup described here and make sure your settings are proper: `https://superuser.com/questions/1042282/zsh-what-does-hist-find-no-dups-mean`